# Randomly select 0 or 1 equal number of times?

Tags: python, random

I want to iterate over 100 values and select randomly 0 or 1, but end up with equal numbers of 0's and 1's,

The code below prints the counts:

```
import random
c_true = 0
c_false = 0

for i in range(100):
    a = random.getrandbits(1)
    if a == 1:
        c_true += 1
    else:
        c_false += 1

print "true_count:",c_true
print "false_count:",c_false
```

The output is:

```
true_count: 56
false_count: 44
```

I want the counts to be equal

```
true_count: 50
false_count: 50
```

How can I change the code to obtain the desired result?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

1. Create `numbers` with 50 0's and 50 1's,

   ```
   >>> numbers = [0, 1] * 50
   ```
2. Import [`shuffle` from `random`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/random.html#random.shuffle)

   ```
   >>> from random import shuffle
   ```
3. `shuffle` them

   ```
   >>> shuffle(numbers)
   ```

**Note:** `shuffle` shuffles the list in-place. So, the `numbers` will be shuffled now.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a generator-based solution that uses O(1) memory:

```
import random

def gen_boolean_seq(true_count, false_count):
   while true_count or false_count:
      val = (random.random() >= false_count / float(true_count + false_count))
      if val:
         true_count -= 1
      else:
         false_count -= 1
      yield val

print sum(gen_boolean_seq(50, 50))
```

Comment: While this satisfies the OP's constraint, so +1, it doesn't give a uniform distribution over all possible sequences and so might not be appropriate for some purposes.

Comment: @DSM: This makes me wonder if there is a known O(1) algorithm that does give uniform distribution over all sequences?

Comment: I think it would suffice to use `(random.random() >= 1.0*false_count / (true_count+false_count))` instead.

Comment: @DSM: It does look like it (empirically, through a little Monte Carlo simulation I've just done). Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

Well its not truely random then but if you want to end up with 50 1s and 50 0s then use a weighting based on how many available places are left. Eg. At 40 1s and 45 0s, the chance of 0 should be 5/15, and the chance of 1 should be 10/15.

Comment: This is a biased algorithm as it will likely end with a long sequence of 0 or 1's at the end. I first thought it would be non deterministic as well, but after 50 zeros or ones the chance would be 100% to generate the other value, so that's not the case.

Comment: Yes, it's biased based on what is left, which is why it is not random.  It's how it would work in the real world if you had a basket of 100 balls, (50 1s, and 50 0s). You can't really ask for complete unbiased randomness, but then add a precondition that the results should be split 50%.  The two things are incompatible.  I'm pretty sure all 3 answers on this question are logically identical.